# How to solve autopostback in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP. application. (A Suervey exactly) And the questions I have put in a table. So 10 questions. The second and 8 questions are radiobutton, in which by clickin the first radiobutton the firt texbox is visible, when clicking the second radiobutton the other textbox gets visible. But the problem is that by every clicking the post back brings me to the top of the page... Is there any trick to not happen this!

Comment: You need to wrap your code with page.ispostback. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: @causita he want to maintain scroll position do you think page.ispostback solve this problem?

Comment: You are correct. Did not read the question properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" in the page directive at the top of your page